# is that possible to exchange the member of a spritegroup in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I randomly share pictures of houses on the screen. Then I drive a car across the screen.When the car hits a house,there are then a number of explosions in the picture of the house. it lasts about 3 seconds. then i want to exchange the picture of the house in the spritegroup for another picture.is that possible to change the member of a spritegroup?

```
 treffer = pygame.sprite.spritecollide( auto, land, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) 
 
        for bumbs in treffer: 
             
            if bumbs not in auto.alte_treffer_liste:                              
                expl = Explosion(bumbs.rect.center,"klein")      
                explosion_group.add(expl)
```

land ist the spritegroup with the pictures of the houses.

in land_copy ist the spritegroup with the copies of the house pictures

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) the sprite and add another sprite. `kill` removes the *Sprite* from all *Groups*. e.g.:

```py
treffer = pygame.sprite.spritecollide( auto, land, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) 
 
for bumbs in treffer: 
             
    if bumbs not in auto.alte_treffer_liste:                              
                
        expl = Explosion(bumbs.rect.center,"klein")      
        explosion_group.add(expl)

        bumbs.kill()                             # <---
```